# Show DataTable depends on file content

Tags: c#, windows-forms-core

I would like to show `DataTable` depends on row value on specific column from a `file`. Key is that I have two different files, with different values.
For example:

1 file with structure:

```
Id;Name;Surname;Sex;Age;
1;AAA;EEE;Male;20;
2;BBB;FFF;Male;20;
3;CCC;GGG;Male;40;
4;DDD;HHH;Male;40;
```

2 File with structure:

```
Id;Name;Surname;Sex;Age;
1;AAA;EEE;Female;20;
2;BBB;FFF;Female;20;
3;CCC;GGG;Female;40;
4;DDD;HHH;Female;40;
```

If I will open file which contains in Column `Sex` value `Male` then it should show only rows with value `20`. `40` is skipped.

If I will open second file which contains in Column `Sex` value `Female` then it should show only rows with value `40`. `20` is skipped.

So, mainly it should looks like:
If I will open 1 file it should show:

```
Id;Name;Surname;Sex;Age;
1;AAA;EEE;Male;20;
2;BBB;FFF;Male;20;
```

If I will open 2 file it should show:

```
Id;Name;Surname;Sex;Age;
3;CCC;GGG;Female;40;
4;DDD;HHH;Female;40;
```

My code so far:

```
table = new DataTable();
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text file|*.txt";
openFileDialog1.Title = "Import file";
openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
if (openFileDialog1.FileName != "")
    {
     reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
     NameFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
     }
     var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog1.FileName);
if (lines.Count() > 0)
     {
     .
     .
     .//some code here not important 
     .
     .
     .
      }
      dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
      }
      DataView dv = table.DefaultView;
      dv.RowFilter = "[Sex] LIKE 'Male' OR [Sex] LIKE  'Female'";
      dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
      dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns();
```

But It shows only Male or Female sex, it should as well somehow filter Age by `20` or `40`. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: DataTable filtered = table.AsEnerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("Age") == 20).CopyToDataTable();

Comment: seems OK, but what in case if I would like to use `if` ? `if male` will cointain `female` then show only values with `20` for example?

Comment: Where(x => (x.Field<int>("Age") == 20) && (x.Field<string>("Sex")  == "Male"))